# Apex Test for setExperienceId

Tags: apex, apextestrunresult

I have a class ForgotUserPassword that uses a community page to set the Experience ID. When I try to build a test class for the setExperienceId, I get an error message saying that “This method can be invoked only from within a community.”

Any ideas on how I can test this?

```
global class ForgotPasswordController {
    //Code for Site.forgotPassword(username) and check if username is valid
     @AuraEnabled
        global static String setExperienceId(String expId) {    
            // Return null if there is no error, else it will return the error message 
            try {
                if (expId != null) {
                    Site.setExperienceId(expId);               
                }
                return null; 
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                system.debug('ex.getMessage is ' +ex.getMessage());
                return ex.getMessage();            
            }        
        }
    }
```

My test class is:

```
@IsTest
     static void testForgotPasswordControllerExperienceId() {
        System.assertEquals(ForgotPasswordController.setExperienceId('1234'), null);
     }
```

EDIT
Here is the code now:

**ISite Class**

```
global interface ISite {
  void setExperienceId(Id experienceId);
}
```

**Class**

```
global class LightningForgotPasswordController {

//<...bunch of unrelated code that works and is covered ...>

class SiteConcrete implements ISite {
    public void setExperienceId(Id experienceID) {
      Site.setExperienceId(experienceId); // the real deal you want in PROD
    }
  }

  @TestVisible static ISite experienceSite = new SiteConcrete(); // enable injection

  @AuraEnabled
    global static String setExperienceId(String expId) {    
        // Return null if there is no error, else it will return the error message 
        try {
            if (expId != null) {
                experienceSite.setExperienceId(expId);               
            }
            return null; 
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            system.debug('ex.getMessage is ' +ex.getMessage());
            return ex.getMessage();            
        }        
    }
}
```

**Test Class**

```
@IsTest
public with sharing class LightningForgotPasswordControllerTest {

//<... unrelated code that works and is covered ...>
    
    class SiteInjected implements ISite {
        Boolean throwException = false;
        public void setExperienceId(Id experienceId) {
            if (this.throwException) {
                throw new System.IllegalArgumentException('mock exception');
            }
            else {}
        }// do nothing, we're just a mock
        SiteInjected(Boolean throwException) {this.throwException = throwException;} // constructor
    }
    
    @IsTest
    static void testLightningForgotPasswordControllerExperienceId() {
        // given no mock exception and some experienceId
        LightningForgotPasswordController.experienceSite = new SiteInjected(false);
        // when controller method called, assert result sb null 
        system.debug('LightningForgotPasswordController.setExperienceId '+LightningForgotPasswordController.setExperienceId(null));       
        //Assert.equals(null,LightningForgotPasswordController.setExperienceId('1234'),
        //              'controller should return null if experienceSiteId is non-null');
        
        // given a mock exception and some experienceId
        LightningForgotPasswordController.experienceSite = new SiteInjected(true);
        // when controller method called, assert result sb error message        
        system.debug('LightningForgotPasswordController.setExperienceId(1234) now is ' +LightningForgotPasswordController.setExperienceId('1234'));
        String res = LightningForgotPasswordController.setExperienceId('1234');
        system.debug('Res is ' +res);
        //Assert.equals('Invalid id: 1234',LightningForgotPasswordController.setExperienceId('1234'), 
        //              'controller should return exception msg if some exception is thrown');
    }
    
    @IsTest
    static void testSiteConcrete(){
        Id myId;
        LightningForgotPasswordController.setExperienceId(myId);
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution to this is dependency injection.

### Define an interface that includes the methods that need to be dependency injected

```
global interface ISite {
  void setExperienceId(Id experienceId);
}
```

### Change your ForgotPasswordController to

```
global class ForgotPasswordController {

  class SiteConcrete implements ISite {
    public void setExperienceId(Id experienceID) {
      Site.setExperienceId(experienceId); // the real deal you want in PROD
    }
  }

  @TestVisible static ISite experienceSite = new SiteConcrete(); // enable injection

  @AuraEnabled
    global static String setExperienceId(String expId) {    
        // Return null if there is no error, else it will return the error message 
        try {
            if (expId != null) {
                experienceSite.setExperienceId(expId);               
            }
            return null; 
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            system.debug('ex.getMessage is ' +ex.getMessage());
            return ex.getMessage();            
        }        
    }
}
```

### Then in the test method, define a mock implementation of ISite

```
class SiteInjected implements ISite {
  Boolean throwException = false;
  public void setExperienceId(Id experienceId) {
    if (this.throwException) {
       throw new System.IllegalArgumentException('mock exception');
    }
    else {} // do nothing, we're just a mock
  }
  SiteInjected(Boolean throwException) {this.throwException = throwException;} // constructor
}
```

### and then inject mock ISite into the code-under-test before invoking

```
@IsTest
   static void testForgotPasswordControllerExperienceId() {
    // given no mock exception and some experienceId
    ForgotPasswordController.experienceSite = new SiteInjected(false);
    // when controller method called, assert result sb null        
    Assert.equals(null,ForgotPasswordController.setExperienceId('1234'),
      'controller should return null if experienceSiteId is non-null');

   // given a mock exception and some experienceId
    ForgotPasswordController.experienceSite = new SiteInjected(true);
    // when controller method called, assert result sb error message        
    Assert.equals('mock exception',ForgotPasswordController.setExperienceId('1234'), 
        'controller should return exception msg if some exception is thrown');
 }
```

This technique is extremely handy to test things where you can't normally mock the environment. The analog is HttpMocks for testing callouts

**Notes**

1. I rearranged the order of arguments for the asserts as the first argument is the *expected value*
2. I provided a way to inject into the mock ISite instructions to throw an exception so you can cover those lines in the code-under-test
3. I may have a typo or two as I did not test this but the pattern is well-known

Comment: Hi @cropredy, thanks for that. I tried implementing what you suggest an I get an error message: "ForgotPasswordController.SiteConcrete: Overriding implementations of global or public interface methods must be global or public: void ISite.setExperienceId(Id)".

I tried putting global and public before "class SiteConcrete implements ISite" but neither worked.

Comment: needs `public` modifier in front of the setExperienceId() implementations; I amended code above

Comment: Thanks. I found a few other typos and was able to get most of them I think. But this part has me stumped:     class SiteInjected implements ISite {
        Boolean throwException = false;
        public void setExperienceId(Id experienceId) {
            if (this.throwException) {
                throw new System.IllegalArgumentException('mock exception');
            }
            else {} // do nothing, we're just a mock
            SiteInjected(Boolean throwException) {
                this.throwException = throwException;
            } // constructor
        }
    }

Comment: 2 errors at the line for SiteInjected(Boolean throwException)

1. Extra ')', at 'throwException'.
2. Variable does not exist: Boolean

Comment: thanks - i fixed the typos

Comment: Thanks. I am still getting those two errors on the line "SiteInjected(Boolean throwException)". The errors are "Extra ')', at 'throwException'." and "Variable does not exist: Boolean"

Comment: Ahh I added a } after the else statement and that worked.

Comment: that's what I get for typing in code directly into SFSE. my apologies. Hopefully, the concept of dependency injection has at least helped :-)

Comment: Cropredy, coming back to this issue. I got most of the code covered but now the section:  "public void setExperienceId(Id experienceID) {
      Site.setExperienceId(experienceId); // the real deal you want in PROD" is not covered. I edited above to show my code as it is now. Perhaps I misunderstood what you meant by "inject mock ISite into the code-under-test before invoking"? Not sure what code-under-test means. I assumed it was just putting the code underneath. But what do I know.

Comment: To get coverage on the `new SiteConcrete().setExperienceId()` you can't - because of what you reported in the OP - but with the injection, you are able to verify that the rest of your controller performs as expected. You don't really need to test `new SiteConcrete().setExperienceId()` because it is a SFDC built-in method and can be guaranteed to work

Comment: Yeah I thought so. My boss just wants the code covered at 90%. I will just have to explain that it can't be. But in this case we don't need it.

Comment: if you need the coverage, then write a testmethod that is `try { new LightningForgotPasswordController.SiteConcrete().setExperienceId() ;} catch (Exception e){}}` - but this proves nothing - just coverage

Comment: Thanks - just how my boss rolls. I had to add  "Id experienceID;" then threw that into the call to the function "setExperienceId(experienceID) " but it worked perfectly.

Comment: Had to make `"class SiteConcrete" @TestVisible too.